# Rcpp not loading boost/asio.hpp

Tags: r, linux, boost, rcpp

I want to include some features from the `boost` library. But when including `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` the file will not compile, see my example:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

> Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpRZlOEQ/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.14/sourcecpp_c4a63bcd586/sourceCpp_32.so") : 
>     unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpRZlOEQ/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.14/sourcecpp_c4a63bcd586/sourceCpp_32.so':
>     /tmp/RtmpRZlOEQ/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.14/sourcecpp_c4a63bcd586/sourceCpp_32.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv

When removing `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` all works fine. Substituting `asio.hpp` with some other files, e.g., `integer.hpp` all works fine.

Here is my `session.Info()`:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.3  magrittr_1.5    rsconnect_0.8.5 tools_3.4.3     yaml_2.1.15     Rcpp_0.12.14    stringi_1.1.6   knitr_1.17     
 [9] stringr_1.2.0   BH_1.65.0-1
```

I also tried it on Windows 10 and loading  is also not possible.

When compiling via g++, all works fine:

```
// test.cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

`g++ test.cpp -lboost_system`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is how it is.  Let me explain, and read on as there *is* a solution for you.

#### Package [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH)

This package is header-only. No linking.  So that you (as package author or users) do not have to mess with `-lboost_system` which becomes a pain across systems quickly.

#### Wait, what?

Right. [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) is header only. And hence does *not* include all of Boost as not all can be had without linking.  *E.g.* no Asio.

#### Say that again? No Asio?

Right. Standard Boost builds leads to requiring Asio with linking. Which is not compatibale with how we do [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH).

#### Sad

Fear not. At some point I discovered that the Asio authors also bundle it a second way, headers-only.  So just use my CRAN package [AsioHeaders](https://cran.r-project.org/package=AsioHeaders) along with [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I never heard before of the `AsioHeaders` package. So I'm excited to use it.

Comment: Sure.  (And I guess you know that your `main.cpp` won't work as that is not how Rcpp works, right?)

Comment: Jap, I already worked with  Rcpp and removed as much as possible to create a MWE.

Comment: Is this also the case for `boost/system/system_error.hpp`?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you need to re-read the parts about "header only", or study [this Rcpp Gallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/). If *you* insist on linking, supply a library. On all OSs.  More work. Your call.